# Fast argument to see that the dual map of a projection is a projection

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

If $X$ is a Banach space and $U,V$ are closed subspaces, such that $X \cong U \oplus V$, then a continuous linear map $P:X \rightarrow X$ is called a projection if $P|_U =id$ and ker(P)=V.

Now we can also look at the dual map $P^*:X^* \rightarrow X^*$. What is the fastest way to see that this must also be a projection? The reason I am asking this is that I want to use it in a presentation and I don't want to give lengthy proofs about the nullspace and the image, if it can be done much faster, as I am only interested in the fact that it is still a projection.

Does anybody here have a good idea how to show this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Projections are characterized by being bounded and idempotent. The dual of $P$ is bounded and also idempotent, as can be seen by dualizing the identity $P^2=P$.

Comment: this is good. it is clear, that my definition of projection implies your one. conversely, we know that $ker(P) $ is closed as $P$ is continuous and $ran(P)$ is closed since we have that $Px_n \rightarrow y$, then also $P(Px_n) \rightarrow Py$ and by using $P^2(x_n) = P(x_n)$ we get $Py=y$ by using continuity. Therefore the range is closed and $x = Px + (Id-P)x$ gives us the decomposition, right?

Comment: That's right.${}{}{}$